# How big is the screen of the Amstrad CPC 464?

Tags: screen, amstrad, cpc464

The Amstrad CPC 464, released in 1984, was distinctive for, among other things, being the first UK home computer to have a built-in monitor instead of assuming you would use a TV set.

How big was the screen of that built-in monitor? That is, I'm not asking about resolution in pixels (Google readily provides that), but physical size in diagonal inches.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The CPC 464 was sold with either a green-screen monitor, [the GT64](https://www.cpcwiki.eu/index.php?title=GT64/GT65), or a colour monitor, [the CTM460](https://www.cpcwiki.eu/index.php/CTM640/CTM644). The former has a 12” tube (11.4” visible), the latter a 14” tube (13.5” visible).

The screen wasn’t built-in to the computer; the computer was in the keyboard unit. The monitor provided the power supply however so wasn’t readily replaceable by other screens, and the system was always sold with a monitor, unlike most other home computers at the time (which were intended to be used with a TV). Amstrad sold [a modulator and power supply](https://www.cpcwiki.eu/index.php/Amstrad_MP1/MP2_modulator) to connect a CPC to a TV; in particular this was presented as an option for the monochrome models to play games on a colour TV.

Comment: Amstrad also sold a couple of RF modulator/power supply units that allowed the use of a TV with the CPC. I'm not sure if you could buy a CPC with the modulator and no monitor as a bundle though.

Comment: Thanks, I’d forgotten about the MP1. I don’t think it was possible to buy a CPC 464 without a monitor.

Comment: A footnote on the MP1: the SAM Coupé uses a modification of it; the SAM’s is either repainted or at least from the same mould, and similarly bundles power and an RF modulator into one box, connecting to the computer with one cable. I have no idea of the business or technical reason why though, alas.